# Paste into Excel without Excel's "intelligent" converting with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to paste data from several sources into Excel on daily basis. The usual way is that you paste the data, then start the text conversion wizzard (translated from german) and make several settings for the delimiter and for the columns. You have to do this, because Excel assumes that 3.4 has to be a date-Format or anything starting with + must be a formula. But in most cases it is not! So I have to pick the columns and set the format from standard to text. Additional, in Germany we do not write 1,223,443.44€ but we write 1.223.443,44€, so each time I have to make this setting also in the wizzard.
So: I want this done with VBA. What I have tried so far:

1. Somehow execute the text conversion wizzard via VBA. But the macro recorder does not record it properly.
2. Selection.TextToColumns: Works fine but the pasted text mus be in one column. When text ist for example tab-delimited, Excel automatically puts it in many columns.
3. Insert in many columns and then by vba collect into one column to use (2). Does not work because at this point the data is already damaged.

The desired behavior is that i can specify the delimiter already before pasting the data in a user friendly dialog, and then paste all data without any poor attempts of excel to interpret it as numbers, formulas, date/time or anything else.
Furthermore I want it to be able to choose number format as 1.000,0 or 1,000.0 in a user friendly dialog, but htis part can also be done after pastinng the data, as long as excel does not already destroy the data with its format assumptions.

Example Data to paste can be:

Part_Number Version Quantity
+213324443  2.3     1,000.00
AZ38643892  1.0        71.11
11.1.89     7.2         0.03

which shows that the + would be interpreted as formula, the version probably as a date and the Quantity at least in german excel would not be the correct numbers.

Comment: Where are you pasting from?

Comment: I am pasting from several sources, like for example results from SQL Queries in SSMS or MySQL Workbench, data from websites or exports from old proprietary software, so each pasting is different. But the code given by Tim helps me very much, as the text conversion wizzard in excel is not the best tool to work with daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the content directly from the clipboard using `DataObject`, but wou would need to figure out exactly what format you wanted for each "column" in that data, and it would also require you to be able to specify the delimiter.

Here's a super-basic example:

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim MyData As New DataObject, arrLines, arrVals, txt, ln, v, c As Range
    Set c = ActiveCell
    
    'get the content from the clipboard
    MyData.GetFromClipboard
    txt = MyData.GetText
    
    arrLines = Split(txt, vbCrLf)            'split to lines
    For ln = 0 To UBound(arrLines)           'loop array of lines
        arrVals = Split(arrLines(ln), vbTab) 'split to values
        For v = 0 To UBound(arrVals)         'loop all values in this line
            With c.Offset(ln, v) 
                .NumberFormat = "@"          'eg. setting all value cells to "Text" format
                .Value = arrVals(v)          'populate the value
            End With
        Next v
    Next ln
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I will use a second sub to convert numbers and dates afterwards.

Comment: To use DATAOBJECT You have to enable Forms 2.0 in the VBA Project.

Comment: Yes, sorry - forgot to mention that.